# Выводит неверный ответ

Tags: ассемблер

Программа должна посчитать выражение `(22/c+3*b)/(36-a*c/3)` для вещественных a и b. Числитель и знаменатель (num,denom) она считает верно, но результат (result) нет. В чем может быть проблема?

```
 .MODEL Large,C
    .data
    Extrn C aaaS:dword,bbbS:dword,cccS:dword,num:dword,denom:dword,result:dword;
    Extrn C ac:dword,bb:dword;
    number22 dd 22
    number3 dd 3
    number36 dd 36
    .code
    Public  Lab3S
Lab3s   proc    far
       FINIT
       FLD bbbS
       FMUL number3
       FST ac
       FLD number22
       FIDIV cccS
       FADD ac
       FSTP num ; save num
       FLD aaaS
       FMUL cccS
       FIDIV number3
       FST bb
       FLD number36
       FSUB bb
       FSTP denom ; save denom
       FLD num
       FIDIV denom
       FSTP result
    ret
Lab3S   endp
    end
```

Comment: как вы знаете, что считает верно если результата нет?

Comment: `FIDIV` делит на целочисленное число, а сохраняешь ты число с плавающей точкой. используй `fdiv`

Comment: @Fat-Zer вам стоит опубликовать свой ответ как решение задачи чтобы за него можно было проголосовать. я хоте бы проголосовать за ваш ответ.

Comment: @ИльяК, если ответ верный, то ИМХО вопрос просто стоит закрыть как опечатку...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код написан верно. Ошибка была в эмуляторе.

```
.MODEL Large,C
    .data
    Extrn C aaaS:dword,bbbS:dword,cccS:dword,num:dword,denom:dword,result:dword;
    Extrn C ac:dword,bb:dword;
    number22 dd 22
    number3 dd 3
    number36 dd 36
    .code
    Public  Lab3S
Lab3s   proc    far
       FINIT
       FLD bbbS
       FMUL number3
       FST ac
       FLD number22
       FIDIV cccS
       FADD ac
       FSTP num
       FLD aaaS
       FMUL cccS
       FIDIV number3
       FST bb
       FLD number36
       FSUB bb
       FSTP denom
       FLD num
       FIDIV denom
       FSTP result
    ret
Lab3S   endp
    end
```